# ODI to feed RavenDB Database

Tags: oracle, ravendb, etl, oracle-data-integrator

Is it possible to feed a RavenDB database with the ETL Oracle Data Integrator ?
What are the recommended solutions to keep a RavenDB Database sync with an Oracle Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Replication Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/bundles/sql-replication) to push data from RavenDB to Oracle, but no - there is nothing built in to either product to push in the other direction.

You could build it yourself if you know where to hook into Oracle with.  It would likely be very specific to your particular use case.